# Streaming Out Extended ASCII

Tags: c++, char, streaming, extended-ascii, wchar

I know that only positive character ASCII values are guaranteed cross platform support.

In Visual Studio 2015, I can do:

```
cout << '\xBA';
```

And it prints:

> ║

When I try that on http://ideone.com I don't print anything.

If I try to directly print this using the literal character:

```
cout << '║';
```

Visual Studio gives the warning:

> warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u2551' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

And then prints:

> ?

When this command is run on http://ideone.com I get:

> 14849425

I've read that `wchar`s may provide a cross platform approach to this. Is that true? Or am I simply out of luck on extended ASCII?

Comment: The important word here is *extended*. "Extended" ASCII is non-standard, and mostly used in Windows. If you want to portably print special characters not in standard ASCII, then your best bet is UTF-8.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Would it be possible to get an example from you of how to print this character using UTF-8 on http://ideone.com?

Comment: Just use `"║"` instead of `'║'`. The type of `'║'` is not char (on ideone) so it won't be printed as a character. The encoding of a string is compiler dependent, but you can force it using prefix (C++11) : `u8"║"` will force UTF-8. How you see the character depends on the console. Windows use a locale dependent encoding (Windows-1252 for you), and ideone use UTF-8.

Comment: @ElderBug Thanks for the explanation. I actually have a good grip on what's going on now. Can I use the `u8` prefix with regular `cout` or is there a special stream like `u8cout` that I need to use? Either way you should post this into an answer.

Comment: Wrote it as an answer. I got carried away so it's a bit longer than intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your input source file has its own encoding. Your compiler needs to be able to read this encoding (maybe with the help of flags/settings).

With a simple string, the compiler is free to do what it wants, but it must yield a `const char[]`. Usually, the compiler keeps the source encoding **when it can**, so the string stored in your program will have the encoding of your input file. There are cases when the compiler will do a conversion, for example if your file is UTF-16 (you can't fit UTF-16 characters in `char`s).

When you use '\xBA', you write a raw character, and you chose yourself your encoding, so there is no encoding from the compiler.

When you use `'║'`, the type of `'║'` is not necessarily `char`. If the character is not representable as a single byte in the compiler character set, its type will be `int`. In the case of Visual Studio with the Windows-1252 source file, `'║'` doesn't fit, so it will be of type `int` and printed as such by `cout <<`.

You can force an encoding with prefixes on string literals. `u8""` will force UTF-8, `u""` UTF-16 and `U""` UTF-32. Note that the `L""` prefix will give you a wide char `wchar_t` string, **but it's still implementation dependent**. Wide chars on Windows are UCS-2 (2 bytes per char), but UTF-32 (4 bytes per char) on linux.

Printing to the console only depends on the type of the variable. `cout <<` is overloaded with all common types, so what it does depends on the type. `cout <<` will usually feed `char` strings as is to the console (actually stdin), and `wcout <<` will usually feed `wchar_t` strings as is. Other combinations may have conversions or interpretations (like feeding an `int`). UTF-8 strings are `char` strings, so `cout <<` should always feed them correctly.

Next, there is the console itself. A console is a totally independent piece of software. You feed it some bytes, it display them. **It doesn't care one bit about your program**. It uses its own encoding, and try to print the bytes you fed using this encoding.

The default console encoding on Windows is Code page 850 (not sure if it is always the case). In your case, your file is CP 1252 and your console is CP 850, which is why you can't print `'║'` directly (CP 1252 doesn't contain `'║'`), but you can using a raw character. You can change the console encoding on Windows with `SetConsoleCP()`.

On linux, the default encoding is UTF-8, which is more convenient because it support the whole Unicode range. Ideone uses linux, so it will use UTF-8. Note that there is the added layer of HTTP and HTML, but they also use UTF-8 for that.

Comment: What about UTF-8 characters. Is there such a thing as `u8'║'`. For example I wanted to do `string(13, '║')`. It sounds like I'll need to find another way to do that, since `u8'║'` is actually 3 characters.

Comment: @JonathanMee `u8'║'` is not valid because `u8''` must be a `char`, and this character doesn't fit. `║` is indeed 3 bytes in UTF-8. You can get a character size in code using `std::string(u8"║").size()`, which will resolve to a constant even with optimizations disabled. You probably have to build the string yourself to fill like you want.

Comment: I'm gonna accept but if you could answer one more comment that would be helpful: When I use `"║"` both http://ideone.com and Visual Studio work fine. I'm leaning toward not bothering with the `u8` prefix. Would there be a situation where using the `u8` prefix would cause this to work where it otherwise wouldn't have?

Comment: @JonathanMee It's hard to tell. `u8` will force UTF-8 instead of source file encoding. On my PC with Visual Studio I can't print `║` with `"║"` nor with `u8"║"`. On Windows, the only thing that works reliably is to use wide chars `wchar_t` with `L` prefixes (but you need to put the console in wide char mode I think). On linux wide chars will be different, but maybe that's the best anyway, since each platform will somewhat make it work the same way, even if the internals are different.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate concepts in play here.

The first one is one of a locale, which is often called "code page" in Microsoft-ese. A locale defines which visual characters are represented by which byte sequence. In your first example, whatever locale your program gets executed as, it shows the "║" character, in response to the byte 0xBA.

Other locales, or code pages, will display different characters for the same bytes. Many locales are multibyte locales, where it can take several bytes to display a single character. In the UTF-8 locale, for example, the same character, ║, takes three bytes to display: 0xE2 0x95 0x91.

The second concept here is one of the source code character set, which comes from the locale in which the source code is edited, before it gets compiled. When you enter the ║ character in your source code, it may get represented, I suppose, either as the 0xBA character, or maybe 0xE2 0x95 0x91 sequence, if your editor uses the UTF-8 locale. The compiler, when it reads the source code, just sees the actual byte sequence. Everything gets reduced to bytes.

Fortunately, all C++ keywords use US-ASCII, so it doesn't matter what character set is used to write C++ code. Until you start using non-Latin characters. Which result in a compiler warning, informing you, basically, that you're using stuff that may or may not work, depending on the eventual locale the resulting program runs in.